# Conditional formatting seems to be not working with dates for me

Tags: date, google-sheets

So, I have this sheet here, where one of the column is dates.
I set up conditional formatting to change the cell color if the day is today, but it seems to be doing nothing even if I change date condition to the exact copy of the cell I expect to change color.

Spreadsheet settings are alright, number format is also alright.
Is there anything I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

try custom formula:

```
=A1*1=DATEVALUE(TODAY())
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.
The problem was in the rules priority.

As soon as I placed the "TODAY" rule before the one that changed color if there's something in the cell, everything worked.

[before, not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdoKW.png)

[after, working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRySH.png)